# When I autoplay an HTML5 video, I can't loop it from a specific point

Tags: javascript, html, video

I have a video that I want to autoplay when the page is loaded, and loop from a specific point (16 seconds) when it ends.  If I add "autoplay" in the HTML the video doesn't loop at all. If I add "loop" in the HTML the video loops but disregards the EventListener.  If I don't add loop or autoplay and play the video manually it loops at 16 seconds like I want it to.

How can I have my video autoplay on page load and also loop at 16 seconds? Below is the code I have:

```js
   document.getElementById('video1').addEventListener('ended', function(){
  this.currentTime = 16; 
  this.play();
  }, false);
```

```html
   <video id="video1" width="100%" autoplay  >
   <source src="video1.webm" type="video/webm">     
    </video>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to reproduce the problem you experienced when I had the code in the *head* tag rather than at the bottom. My test which worked looked like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>html video</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div >
        <video id="video1" width="100%" autoplay controls>
            <source src="test2.webm" type="video/webm">           
        </video>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script>
        document.getElementById('video1').addEventListener('ended', function(){
                this.currentTime = 16; 
                this.play();
        }, false);
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: That was it! Can't believe the fix was that simple. I read that javascript shouldn't go at the top (I had it at the top of the body) but I didn't understand that it actually affected things, guess i'll put it all at the bottom.

Comment: the reason is because the javascript was activating before the `<video>` was instantiated so the function had nothing to register against